# Book where a boy finds out he's the new king of an icy kingdom and can turn into a dragon

Tags: story-identification, books

The book I'm looking for is about a boy whose mom lived in the city until one day people show up talking about how he is the new king of an icy kingdom. He moves there, where his step mother lives, and falls in love with a maid and he can turn into a dragon, I think. The maid studies under a herbalist and that's all I remember. It's like a 3 book series.

I think it was published in the early 2000s.

Comment: Can you give us a clue, like when was it published?

Comment: I think early 2000s

Comment: Do you happen to remember anything about hair color or skin color of the characters?

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1400424.The_Dragon_s_Eye is a partial match, but not good enough of one for me to post it as an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Young adult series about a prince in a northern setting kingdom who can turn into a dragon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126969/young-adult-series-about-a-prince-in-a-northern-setting-kingdom-who-can-turn-int)

Comment: @Turamarth: Do you want to post that as an answer, in case Siah5 does not come back? Answers are searchable, but comments are not.

Comment: No that's not it I'm not sure of the skin or hair. I do remember his step mom wants to take over and he falls in love with his maid and she helps heal him after he transform.